# How can I have both TCP and REST API on puma?

Tags: tcp, puma

Is there an easy way to enable TCP connectivity for the default puma rails server? 
My use case need is to start my rest api puma server and enable TCP connections as well, so that when I call a specific endpoint and use some TCP service inside the rest api it would keep connection alive.

Is this possible? I am not talking about websockets, but TCP pure sockets.

Comment: The question (and use case) isn't clear. Do you want add a raw TCP client to your Rails application or do you expect Puma to accept raw TCP/IP connections. If Puma should listen to TCP connections, is it on the same port? If it's on the same port, how does Puma know it's a raw TCP client as opposed to an HTTP client (are you using some custom Upgrade scheme)? If it's not the same port, did you consider using iodine (an alternative server)?

Comment: The idea is that the server accepts raw TCP/IP connections. The main use case is to keep the connection alive for purposes of speed. It could run on different port, but both the TCP and the HTTPS should be able to access the database and communicate between each other. On starting the rails server it keeps the connection of the tcp alive